# OpenStack Keystone: "The service catalog is empty." after issuing any command

Tags: centos7, openstack, keystone

I'm just back after installing Keystone following the [OpenStack docs: Install and configure of Keystone](https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/stein/install/keystone-install-rdo.html).

I'm running CentOS 7 and OpenStack Stein.

I've noted on this page a missing step on the recipe (`keystone-manage db_sync` that creates the tables on keystone DB and `keystone-manage bootstrap` ... well, I'd like to know what exactly performs this command!).

Well, issuing the command:

`openstack domain create --description "An Example Domain" example`

(as documented in [Create a domain, projects, users, and roles](https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/stein/install/keystone-users-rdo.html)) I get the following message:

`The service catalog is empty.`

Also issuing the command `openstack domain list` I get the same result.

On `/var/log/keystone.log` I have:

`WARNING keystone.access_rules_config.backends.json [-] No config file found for access rules, application credential access rules will be unavailable.: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/keystone/access_rules.json'`

On `/var/log/httpd/keystone_access.log` I have all `201` (Created) status or `200` when raising commands.

So, it's sure I'm missing something in my configuration; I've already googled around with no results; any help will be strongly appreciated.

Comment: OpenStack is a huge piece of software and needs some skills and a lot of patience to get working for the first time. If your service catalog is empty means basically your keystone haven't issue any token for the other service, a minimal installation will require at least the following in the catalog: identity, network, image, placement and compute. So  Keystone, Neutron, Glance, Nova Cloud Controller and Nova Compute. You could check if your database and service are running.

Comment: @AngelHumbertoVargas ... or simply remember to populate the DB with `# su -s /bin/sh -c "keystone-manage db_sync" keystone` , command that I have missing while configuring! :-)
Thanks for help anyway! :-D